# Nested List/Tuple

Tags: python

Hi i have written a code that moves the location of an element in a nested list to a specific place (location given by tuple)

```
#w=width
#h=height
#m=location to move(x,y)
location=[]

def grid(w,h,m)
    for i in range(h):
        new_grid = []
        location.append(new_grid)
        for j in range(w):
            if (i, j) == m:
                new_grid.append('(a)')
            else:     
               new_grid.append('(_)')
```

I need the function to first look at the x coordinate for eg(1,3), it would first move to the second row then move down 3. The function i wrote only looks at the inner list given by the x coordinate. Also this functions not supposed to return just change the location variable

Any help is appreciated Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `move to second row and then down` ? Does it mean move 4 places down (row-wise)?

Comment: basically it starts off at (0,0) then if its (1,3) it would move it one to the right then 3 down and yes row wise it would be 4

Comment: Why not just look at `y` co-ordinate -> go that many rows down -> look at `x` co-ordinate -> go that many rows right ?

Comment: its suppose to look at the x first

Comment: It should not actually matter since you will be going to same location. However, I will try to write answer in couple of minutes

Comment: alright thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simplify along the following lines? You do fill one cell twice, but it is significantly more readable. Note that if you want to alter a [global](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) variable by assignment, you have to declare it as such in the function:

```
location = []

def grid(w, h, m):
    global location
    location = [w * ['(_)'] for i in range(h)]
    location[m[1]][m[0]] = '(a)'

> grid(2, 4, (1, 3))
print(location)
[['(_)', '(_)'], ['(_)', '(_)'], ['(_)', '(_)'], ['(_)', '(a)']]
> grid(2, 4, (0, 2))
print(location)
[['(_)', '(_)'], ['(_)', '(_)'], ['(a)', '(_)'], ['(_)', '(_)']]
```

Comment: if i want to add another element to move besides just (a) how would i do that, like where in your code would that be added

Comment: E.g. `location[3][0] = '(a)'`

Comment: actually i just realized its not supposed to return anything just change the location variable

Comment: If it is supposed to change the location variable, why are you passing it the dimension parameters to build it from scratch?

Comment: yea basically this function is just supposed to add to the variable then a different function will adjust it more